# how to create a android Titanium module with ".AAR" file?

Tags: android, module, appcelerator-titanium

I am building a android module in Titanium in which I have a ".aar" file available to use the sdk of the hardware .

how can I develop a module using ".aar" file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Titanium native modules do not support AAR files. There is an open issue on their JIRA.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-18565

As a work around you can always rename the *.aar file to *.zip and extract the contents. I have done this and just included the JARs in the lib directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Collin ,

I have extracted JAR from AAR and used some other dependencies together . 

This worked for me  !!!

Comment: That's great to hear! Would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks.